# Delete duplicate couples nested implicitly in nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have built a nested dictionary which represent all combinations (cartesian product) valued with a counter.

Couples are *implicit* and also (g1,g2) is the same as (g2,g1)

This is my code for my structure

```
counters_in_group = dict((group,0) for group in arr)
counters = dict((group, dict(counters_in_group)) for group in arr)
print(counters)
```

Saying groups is `arr = [7272463, 8980365, 7047095]` I am getting this

```
{7047095: {7272463: 0, 8980365: 0, 7047095: 0}, 8980365: {7272463: 0, 8980365: 0, 7047095: 0}, 7272463: {7272463: 0, 8980365: 0, 7047095: 0}}
```

I would like to simply get rid of duplicates so

```
{7047095: {7272463: 0, 8980365: 0, 7047095: 0}, 8980365: {7272463: 0, 8980365: 0}, 7272463: {7272463: 0}}
```

I hope the question is clear, I will try to clarify more if needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the groups always integers?

Comment: groups are IDs, I can use IDs names (Strings) instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the **elements are orderable** (so a `<=` relation is defined over these like `int`, `str`,...), you can use the following nested dictionary comprehension:

```
{k1:{k2:v2 for k2,v2 in v1.items() if k1 <= k2} for k1,v1 in counters.items()}
```

This creates:

```
>>> {k1:{k2:v2 for k2,v2 in v1.items() if k1 <= k2} for k1,v1 in counters.items()}
{7047095: {7272463: 0, 8980365: 0, 7047095: 0}, 8980365: {8980365: 0}, 7272463: {8980365: 0, 7272463: 0}}
```

The code works as follows: for every couple `(g1,g2)` we simply put the value into the resulting dictionary, if and only if `g1 <= g2`. So that means that one of the two duplicates is added, and one is removed.

Comment: very cleaver, I'll mark it as a solution as I'm in a hurry, and review it's genius later.

Comment: I just replaced < with <= to include (val1, val1)s

Comment: @bacloud14: I noticed that a combination can also be constructed out of the same elements. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> {k: dict.fromkeys(arr[i:], 0) for i, k in enumerate(arr)}
{7047095: {7047095: 0}, 8980365: {8980365: 0, 7047095: 0}, 7272463: {7047095: 0, 8980365: 0, 7272463: 0}}
```

or

```
>>> {k1: {k2: 0 for k2 in arr[i:]} for i, k1 in enumerate(arr)}
{7047095: {7047095: 0}, 8980365: {8980365: 0, 7047095: 0}, 7272463: {7047095: 0, 8980365: 0, 7272463: 0}}
```